# HTML/PHP contact form not working on Heroku

Tags: php, html, forms, heroku

I've created a contact form on my website that worked using xampp server but it's not working on Heroku.

this is the HTML:

```
<form action="../php/contact.php" method="post">

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Name</label>   
                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control frame" required>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>email</label>
                <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control frame" required>
            </div>

            <br>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Message</label>    
                <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="" rows="" class="form-control frame"></textarea>
            </div>

            <br>

            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="submit" name="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

And this is the PHP:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$visitorEmail = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$emailFrom = 'haizler.co.il';
$emailSubject = "New Form Submission";
$emailBody = "User Name: $name.\n".
                "User Email: $visitorEmail.\n".
                "User Message: $message.\n";

$to = "realMailOnOriginalCode@gmail.com";
$headers = "From: $emailFrom \r\n";
$headers .= "Replay-To: $visitorEmail \r\n";
mail($to,$emailSubject,$emailBody,$headers);
header("Location: contact.html");
?>
```

When filling the detail and clicking Send I get "Cannot POST /php/contact.php".
I've tried changing the php address on the form action, and also tried putting the php file in the same folder has the html file but it didn't work.

This code worked using xampp (after changing the definitions on php.ini xampp file).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you checked that the path that you're posting to is correct?

Comment: relative links again. always a bad idea. let me guess, your XAMPP address is something like `http://localhost/some-folder/index.php` ? Whereras the  heroku one just has `http://example.com/index.php`?

Comment: When submitting form, check the url in the browser, it should give a 404 when path is not right.

Comment: @delboy1978uk in XAMPP I don't reach the php part because when I press "send" it just sends the message and refresh the page. The address of the contact form is basically http://localhost/some-folder1/some-folder2/contact.html, whereas the address in Heroku is https://example.com/view/contact.html
When clicking on "send" on Heroku I get "Cannot POST /php/contact.php" and the address is https://example.com/php/contact.php

Comment: @mattfryercom I checked, and also how can it be wrong if it works with XAMPP?

Comment: try adding the PHP to the beginning of the file and add `action=""` This will post the file to itself and you won't have to worry about the path. If that doesn't work we know it's not a problem with the path.

You'll have to add a condition at the beginning of the PHP like `if ($_POST['submit']) { /* add the rest of the PHP here */ }`

Comment: @mattfryercom did what you said but it's still not working

Comment: is the condition working? just test the `if` statement by echoing something if the form submits. If that works, then put your PHP inside that conditional statement. Simplify the problem, just see if you can get the form to submit to the same page and echo something inside the conditional statement if the form submits. Maybe try `if (!empty($_POST['submit'])) { echo 'form submitted'; }`. Also try adding a value to the `button` like `<button value="submit">submit</button>`, obviously keep the other attributes too.

Comment: To clarify I'm saying that if you submit the form to the same page, you need to change the `.html` file extension to `.php` and add the PHP at the top of the HTML file.

Comment: What happens if you just have the HTML submitting to the same page with `action=""` and don't have any PHP in the file? so just test if the HTML form submits.

Comment: When action="" I still get "Cannot POST /view/contact.html"

Comment: @YardenA Try just this with nothing else on the page to simplify the issue as much as possible, if that doesn't work, you'll probably need to update something in `php.ini`: `<form action="" method="post"><button type="submit">Submit</button></form>` - I hope that helps, let me know the result.

Comment: @mattfryercom thanks for the help but I think I will search for an alternative for this specific form... I don't think I have access to a php.ini file on Heroku and I can't find anything about this problem in general on google.

Comment: @YardenA No problem, this may help: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-php-settings#php-runtime-settings

Comment: Fix your XAMPP, not heroku. Set up a virtual host in the apache conf extra folder. then tweak the code to get it working again locally, and when you deploy it shhould be dfine